# Squeezing performance out of v8

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js

Are there any good tutorials on how to write fast, efficient code for v8 (specifically, for node.js)?

What structures should I avoid using? What are the idioms that v8 optimises well?

Comment: Just curious, but why are you asking?  Shouldn't you be more concerned about squeezing performance out of the slowest (but widely used) rendering engines than the fastest one?  Seems the fastest will take care of itself.

Comment: I just want to know what v8 doesn't like. Efficient code matters to me.

Comment: Good reply nornagon - its incredibly frustrating when the question is disregard and responses are unrelated. I too am interested simply for interests sake!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From my experience:

- It does inlining
- Function call overhead is minimal (inlining)
- What is expensive is to pass huge strings to functions, since those need to be copied and from my experience V8 isn't always as smart as it could be in this case
- Scope lookup is expensive (surprise)
- Don't do tricks e.g. I have a binary encoder for JS Object, cranking out some extra performance with bit shifting there (instead of Math.floor) latest [Crankshaft](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/12/new-crankshaft-for-v8.html) (yes alpha, but still) runs the code 30% slower
- Don't use magic. eval, arguments.callee etc. Those pretty much kill any optimization since code can no longer be inlined
- Some of the new ES5 stuff e.g. `.bind()` is *really* slow in V8 at the moment
- Somehow `new Object()` and `new Array()` are a bit faster currently (MICROoptimization, unless you're writing some crazy encoder stick with `{}` and `[]`)

My rules:

- Write good code
- Write working code
- Write code that works in strict mode (support still has [to land](http://codereview.chromium.org/6144005/), but when it does further optimization can be applied by V8)

If you're an JS expert and your already applying all [good practices](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/) to your code, there's hardly anything you can do to improve performance.

If you encounter performance issues:

- Verify them
- Change the code / algorithm
- And as a last resort: Write a C++ extension (and watch *every* commit to ry/node on GitHub since nobody cares whether some internal changes break your build)

Comment: Thanks -- Javascript Garden looks awesome :)

Comment: This is an old post but I recently came across some nice video (from Google IO 2012) about exact thing. It was published in 2012, so things have changed a bit but I guess not much: http://youtu.be/UJPdhx5zTaw

Answer (score 0):

The docs give a great answer: http://code.google.com/apis/v8/design.html

Comment: The docs aren't quite enough. eg: does v8 do inlining? How expensive is a function call? How expensive is creating an object? I want to know how clever v8 is in a wide variety of cases, not just property accesses.

Answer (score 0):

[Understanding V8](http://s3.mrale.ph/nodecamp.eu/) is a set of slides from nodecamp.eu and gives very some interesting tips.  In particular, I found the notes on avoiding "dictionary mode" useful i.e. it helps if you keep the "shape" of objects constant and don't add arbitrary properties to them.

You should also run node with `--crankshaft --trace-opt --trace-bailout` (the `--crankshaft` is only needed on 64-bit platforms e.g. OS X) to see whether V8 is "bailing" on JITing certain functions.  There is a ton of other trace options including `--trace-gc` and various other GC tracing, which can be useful for optimisation.

Let me know if you have any specific questions about the slides above as they're a bit concise. :-)  They're not mine but I've done some research about the areas they cover.