# Gaining performance writing the same code?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js

I'm wondering if

```
function pathJoin(uri,file){
    return url.format(
        url.parse(
            path.normalize(
                path.join(uri, file) 
            ).split(
                path.delimiter
            ).join("/")
        )
    );
}
```

and

```
function pathJoin(uri,file){
    var joined_path = path.join(uri, file);
    var normalized = path.normalize( joined_path );
    var splitted = normalized.split(path.delimiter);
    var joined = splitted.join("/");
    var parsed = url.parse(joined);
    return url.format(parsed);
}
```

will perform equally fast. 
Isn't there any penalization for switching from function to function multiple times?

Comment: @tucuxi Does jsperf support NodeJS?  (because that uses path and url from NodeJS)

Comment: Just benchmark it. Benchmark.js Then there's no need to wonder and you can use your real data as well. jsperf.com uses Benchmark in the backgroun AFAIK and it doesn't support Node.js directly. @alexandernst

Comment: Hmm, you are right. Otoh, the source for those functions seems to be standard JS: https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/path.js. Results for jsperf under chrome (also uses V8) should be similar to those experienced under node.js

Answer (score 5):

Note: path.join already returns a normalized path. They have the same performance... And don't use jsperf to benchmark node things.

**CODE**

```
var path = require ("path");
var url = require ("url");
var speedy = require ("speedy");

function pathJoin(uri,file){
    return url.format(
        url.parse(
            path.normalize(
                path.join(uri, file) 
            ).split(
                path.delimiter
            ).join("/")
        )
    );
}

function pathJoin2(uri,file){
    var joined_path = path.join(uri, file);
    var normalized = path.normalize( joined_path );
    var splitted = normalized.split(path.delimiter);
    var joined = splitted.join("/");
    var parsed = url.parse(joined);
    return url.format(parsed);
}

speedy.timeout (20000);
speedy.run ({
    "1": function (){
        pathJoin ("http://www.google.com", "file");
    },
    "2": function (){
        pathJoin2 ("http://www.google.com", "file");
    }
})
```

**RESULT**

```
File: t.js

Node v0.10.20
V8 v3.14.5.9
Speedy v0.0.8

Benchmarks: 2
Timeout: 20000ms (20s 0ms)
Samples: 3
Total time per benchmark: ~60000ms (1m 0s 0ms)
Total time: ~120000ms (2m 0s 0ms)

Higher is better (ops/sec)

1
  50,931 ± 0.1%
2
  51,029 ± 0.1%

Elapsed time: 120063ms (2m 0s 63ms)
```

Comment: My concern is that isn't there any overheap at all? Also, can you re-run this, but make it run a little bit longer. Perhaps 20s per function?

Comment: Node runs on V8 -- according to this, V8 already does many behind-the-scenes optimizations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710396/squeezing-performance-out-of-v8

Comment: No overhead, no nothing. Updating answer... with 1min per function

Comment: @tucuxi the accepted answer there isn't really good... in fact reality is completely opposite. In general, the more "idiomatic js" your code is, the slower it runs. The more it is written as if js was static language, the faster it is.

Answer (score 4):

Generally syntactic differences never affect performance. The compiler doesn't operate at the source code level.

In practice there are exceptions of course. In the following for example V8 is not smart enough to optimize the latter:

```
function a(arg) {
    return typeof arg === "string";
}

function b(arg) {
    var tmp = typeof arg;
    return tmp === "string";
}
```

The latter will actually lookup the type string for the variable, and then compare the string to `"string"` - rather than checking if `arg` is a string which is what the code semantically does. Check how radically different the generated code for the functions are: http://pastebin.com/h7PsV39p

This is also funny because people optimize by "caching typeof", in the process they are making it much slower because V8 only recognizes full uncached typeof expressions.

Comment: Yeah, but my concern is that this isn't just a syntactic difference, but rather an overheap, as the first way I'm nesting function calls.

Comment: @alexandernst I didn't read the first code because it's unreadable but I assume the only difference is temporary variables, in which case my answer stands.

Comment: Generally speaking there is no theoretical reason for generating worse code in the second case. It's just that `typeof v === str` recognition greatly predates Crankshaft which made it possible. And when Crankshaft was developed nobody bothered to move pattern recognition to the place where it belongs.

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov yeah I have clarified that in practice you can find exceptions like this :-)

Comment: how do you print the machine code? benchmark results: without caching is 1,8 times faster, very odd: https://github.com/gagle/node-speedy/blob/master/examples/typeof.js

Comment: @GabrielLlamas almost the whole point of my post is that without caching is faster. And don't write benchmarks like that, your code could be completely eliminated because it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Esailija "could", but in fact the v8 does not optimize that. Anyway, the bench result reaffirms your answer.

Comment: @GabrielLlamas to print the code, [build v8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP) either in debug mode or with disassembler enabled. Then run some code that calls functions in an infinite loop with flags `--print_opt_code --code_comments` (or you can alternatively use the flag `--allow-natives-syntax` and call `%OptimizeFunctionOnNextCall` instead of looping)